# Bug with SKScene size

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, aspect-ratio, spriteview

Could somebody please help me with this issue: I can't understand why my SKScene moves few points right when I try to add aspect ratio to background image (I removed transparency from scene so you can see the problem with it's size)? Is this swiftUI bug or I am doing something wrong?

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct MenuScreenView: View {
    
    @Bindable var player: Player
    private let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    private let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = MenuScene()
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        return scene
    }
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background2")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight, alignment: .center)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - Preview
#Preview {
    MenuScreenView(player: Player(name: "Name", score: 100, ship: .frigate, ammo: [.missile: 100]))
}
```

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {
    
    override init() {
        super.init(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodesAtPoint = nodes(at: location)
        
        for node in nodesAtPoint {
            if let nodeName = node.name {
                print("\(nodeName) button tapped!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        if isSavedGameExist() {
            createMenuButtonWith(continueTitle, at: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + 60))
        }
        createMenuButtonWith(newGameTitle, at: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + 20))
        createMenuButtonWith(scoreTitle, at: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY - 20))
        createMenuButtonWith(settingsTitle, at: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY - 60))
    }
    
    private func createMenuButtonWith(_ text: String, at position: CGPoint) {
        let button = MenuButton(buttonText: text)
        button.position = position
        addChild(button)
    }
    
    private func isSavedGameExist() -> Bool {
        // TODO: Add logic of check for existing game
        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: - Localization helpers
    
    private var newGameTitle: String {
        NSLocalizedString(Localizable.menuNewGameButtonTitle, comment: "")
    }
    private var settingsTitle: String {
        NSLocalizedString(Localizable.menuSettingsButtonTitle, comment: "")
    }
    private var scoreTitle: String {
        NSLocalizedString(Localizable.menuScoreButtonTitle, comment: "")
    }
    private var continueTitle: String {
        NSLocalizedString(Localizable.menuContinueButtonTitle, comment: "")
    }
}
```

[bug is here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1HNX.png)

[looks normal without aspect ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvQK9.png)

Comment: remove this line: `.frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight, alignment: .center)`

Comment: @Fault but it breaks the size of skscene on ipad device :(